# Fullcalendar not showing March 31st events

Tags: fullcalendar

I have been using fullcalendar plugin successfully for a few months and suddenly ran into a bug.  It won't display an event on March 31st 2012.  This behavior doesn't happen on our test site server running php v5.3.8, but does on our live site server.  That server is running php v5.3.6.

Can someone shed some light on this situation.  Is it possibly related to daylight savings?  How do I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: "true",
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        header: {
            left: "",
            center: "prev title next",
            right: ""
        },
        buttonIcons:{
            prev: "triangle-1-w",
            next: "triangle-1-e"
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: 'VS_race_events.php',  // Event Source One //
                type: 'POST',
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                color: '#006600',
                textColor: 'white'
            },
            {
                url: 'VS_work_events.php',  // Event Source Two //
                type: 'POST',
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                borderColor: '#006600',
                color: 'beige',
                textColor: '#333333'
            }
        ],
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#dialog_frame").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#dialog_frame").draggable("enable");
            $(".dialog_content").html(calEvent.description);
            $(".dialog_title").html(calEvent.title);         
        }   
    })
});
</script>
```

Here is VS_work_event file:

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/HDAdavePDO.php');

if (isset($_POST['start'])) {
  $unix_start = $_POST['start'];
  $date_start = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$unix_start);

}
if (isset($_POST['end'])) {
  $unix_end = $_POST['end'];
  $date_end = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",$unix_end);
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM vs_events WHERE event_date >= ? AND event_date < ?');
$stmt2->bindParam(1, $date_start);
$stmt2->bindParam(2, $date_end);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row_Calendar = $stmt2->fetchAll();

foreach ($row_Calendar as $row){
    if ($row['event_type'] == 13 && $row['active'] == 1){
    $display_date = substr($row['event_date'],0,10);
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['event_id'];
    $eventsArray['start'] = $display_date;
    $eventsArray['title'] = $row['event_subject'];
    $eventsArray['description'] = $row['event_text'];
    $eventsArray['type'] = $row['event_type'];
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}
}
echo json_encode($events);
$pdo = null;
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide way more details, some code, the JSON that is populating the FullCalendar source, etc.

Comment: Here's a link to the calendar page that is not displaying March 31st events.  http://vinery.com.previewdns.com/VRcalendar.php

Comment: Brandon - I have added my script and data source files to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSON response of both of your event sources, there is no event that I can see that takes place on March 31st.

Your issue is likely on your server side querying of events or the event record itself, and not with FullCalendar.

Comment: The event is in the database but doesn't show up on the calendar unless I move the date of the event to March 30 or April 1.

Comment: I have tried echoing the JSON response to screen and found that the March 31st events are not included when an end date of March 31 is used.  However, when an end date of April 1 is used the March 31st dated events are then included in the JSON response.  This doesn't happen with other months.  May 31st events appear properly as do March 31st 2011 events.  I did try to research this before posting as a question.

Comment: Brandon - I now see the problem is with in the file making the JSON call.  The database is not returning a March 31st event when the end date of the query is March 31st.  I don't know why this happens on one php server and not another.  I am looking into that now.

Comment: Ended up adding 86399 to the Unix End Date: $unix_end = $_POST['end']+86399;

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM vs_events WHERE event_date >= ? AND event_date < ?');
```

so if $date_end is 31st March, 31st March events won't be returned by this query as

```
31st March <  31st March is **false**
```